# How can i use result in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new user of android studio. I am using priority in manifest file and  all required permissions but I do not know how can I use result in main activity, help me out.

````
public abstract class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   
    protected abstract void onSmsReceived(SmsMessage smsMessage);```

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pduObjectList = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pduObjectList != null) {
                for (Object pduObject : pduObjectList) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduObject);
                    onSmsReceived(smsMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: what is result? the sms message?

Comment: FelipeCruzV10 yes the sms message the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract keyword is a non-access modifier, used for classes and methods:

Abstract class: is a restricted class that cannot be used to create objects (to access it, it must be inherited from another class).

Abstract method: can only be used in an abstract class, and it does not have a body. The body is provided by the subclass (inherited from).

**In your activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private smsReceiver SmsBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_one_position);
        smsReceiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver() {

            // this code is call asyncrously from the receiver
            @Override
            protected void onSmsReceived() {
                 // Add your activty logic here
            }

        };

    }

     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            this.unregisterReceiver(this.smsReceiver);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is by using static variables.

On the MainActivity add the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static SmsMessage result;
    //...
}
```

Then, add the following line `MainActivity.result = smsMessage` to the code you provided just after you get the message.

Then you can use the variable `result` in any part of the MainActivity (also by calling `MainActivity.result` you have the value of the variable in any part of your code).

Just be careful, static variables are defined as `null` before any assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API used so this is easily getting in SMS,So there was no problem and No permission is needed

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview